# Kotlin Multiplatform app not found iOS simulator

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I am facing a problem to run iOS app from the Kotlin Multiplatform app. I could not config execution target to run in iOS. Although my environment seems that my environment is ready.[image: System ready status]

I try to update pod init and pod install but doesn't work. Also change the java version to 11.

Comment: I have faced the same issue. It can be solved by downloading latest ios simulators SDK from Xcode

Comment: I have the latest simulator installed in my system i can see iOS: 17.0

Please check the link image:
 https://ibb.co/kXvcxYS

Comment: what it present is ios SDK not simulator sdk you need ios 17.0 simulator which you can add by clicking + button below left corner check this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRJ6l.png